# Kung Fu Scientist Killed and Resurrected While Investigating Aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a novel from mid-80's or before. I think it was part of a series. A scientist was brought in to investigate some alien artifacts or something.  The government was holding him prisoner during the investigation, but he showed them that he was a kung-fu fighter by kicking and bending a fence post. He eventually is killed and then resurrected (perhaps in the sequel).  I think the cover of one of the books had the scientist standing in front of a rainbow-like light.

Comment: I'm sure I remember this scene, but sadly nothing else from the book. In the hope it jogs memories: the imprisoned scientist is in the exercise yard where his daily exercise is doing karate katas. For some reason (I forget why) he starts kicking a fence post and only stops when a guard shouts at him. I think the character is described as being *inwardly always angry*. The book had a thriller feel - like a Michael Crichton novel, though I've been through all his books and I don't think it is one of those.